# Mongo index [String] property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongoose-schema

I was just reviewing some code, and saw such property in the mongoose scheme:

```
names: {
  type: [String],
  index: true
}
```

As far as I understand how indexes work, they are binary trees, and how is this going to be organized as a node of a tree? Is there at all any sense of indexing such property?

Comment: I see the username choice is appropriate https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: @NeilLunn I didn't get your point. If you're talking about 'names' property, it can be any, brands, cars whatever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'If you index a field that holds an array value, MongoDB creates separate index entries for every element of the array.' Per [MongoDB documentation on multikey index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).